# The service upgrade package and the currently deployed service have different numbers or types of input endpoints

Tags: windows, azure

I am getting bellow Error while deploying package on staging server

The service upgrade package and the currently deployed service have different numbers or types of input endpoints for role ABC. An upgrade is not supported in this case. The long running operation tracking ID was: b109f8bbe2a41c72a35492f345594587.

Answer (score 1):

A you using an older (pre 1.5) version of the Azure SDK? In place upgrades to a cloud service with changes to the number/type of endpoints is only supported on 1.5 or later.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply . I am using Azure SDK 2.4 latest version

Comment: Then I'd recommend you open a support ticket because changing endpoints is supported post 1.5. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates/